# Is there any possible way to move OS from SSD to HDD? SSD has dual boot

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, multi-boot, clone

I have SSD and HDD on my laptop. I made partitioned the SSD and installed Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18 in SSD (dual boot).

My SSD size is only 250GB (both OS installed here) and HDD size is 1TB.

Now I want to move Windows 10 (not reinstalled, just move) to a HDD and keep existing Ubuntu 18 own the SSD.

What is the easiest way for this without data loss?

Comment: As long as both have been installed in UEFI mode - as they should be - all you have to do is clone/move the Windows system partition to the intended drive. Then both Ubuntu as usual and run `sudo update-grub`. Do not touch the ESP (EFI System Partition).

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia It seems like your comment could be reposted as an answer to the question.

Comment: Reposted as answer. I wish I could give more details but the scarcity of information in the OP doesn't allow other way.

Comment: And keep in mind that running Windows or any other OS from the HDD will be a lot slower than it was before. You've been warned.

Comment: Clone complete SSD with any cloning software of your choice and boot into HDD , check if everything works fine and after that delete the Ubuntu partition

Answer (score 0):

As long as both have been installed in UEFI mode - as they should be - all you have to do is clone/move the Windows system partition to the intended drive. Then boot Ubuntu as usual and run `sudo update-grub`.

Do not touch the ESP (EFI System Partition).